# Split DataFrame column based on regex expression with OR

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

I have a dataframe with several columns of user information where I have the columns "Contact 1" and "Contact 2".

```
d= {'Contact 1': ['1234567891 1234567891', '12345678 12345678', '12345678 1234567891', '1234567891 12345678','1234567 1234567891',
          '1234567891','123456789 12345678911', None],
    'Contact 2': [None, None, None, None, None, '12345678', None, None]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

| Contact 1 | Contact 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567891 1234567891 | None |
| 12345678 12345678 | None |
| 12345678 1234567891 | None |
| 1234567891 12345678 | None |
| 1234567 1234567891 | None |
| 1234567891 | 12345678 |
| 123456789 12345678911 | None |
| None | None |

I want to split the "Contact 1" column based on the space between numbers only if the contact numbers are 8 or 10 digits followed by space, then 8 or 10 digits. This while also preserving the few information I have on "Contact 2" column.

I tried the following code:

```
df[['Contact 1', 'Contact 2']]=df['Contact 1'].str.split(r'(?<=^\d{8}|\d{10})\s(?=\d{8}|\d{10}$)', n=1, expand=True)
```

but I get the error "re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern"

I would like to get the following result:

| Contact 1 | Contact 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567891 | 1234567891 |
| 12345678 | 12345678 |
| 12345678 | 1234567891 |
| 1234567891 | 12345678 |
| 1234567 1234567891 | None |
| 1234567891 | 12345678 |
| 123456789 12345678911 | None |
| None | None |

Comment: Could you please explain how line `12345678  1234567891` 's Contact 2 column got value after processing?

Comment: Yes. Since 12345678  1234567891 is composed of a 8 or 10 digit number (in this case 8) followed by a whitespace, and then a number composed of 8 or 10 digits (in this case 10), the second number should be splitted to column 'Contact 2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in a non-regex solution:

Create a mask or rows that meet your conditions

```
m = df['Contact 1'].str.split().apply(lambda x: all([len(n) in [8,10] for n in x]))
```

Update df with the split/expanded values

```
df.update(df.loc[m]['Contact 1'].str.split(expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Contact 1',
                                                                        1:'Contact 2'}), overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for my small dataframe, but when I try to run your first line of code on my real dataframe of 75,000 rows I get the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" which is weird since we just proved with the small dataframe that it works with None values.

Comment: I wrote the exception for None as follows `m = df['Contact 1'].str.split().apply(lambda x: all([len(n) in [8,10] for n in x]) if x != None else False)`  and it works now :D  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.extract`:

```py
df["Contact 2"] = np.where(df["Contact 2"].isnull(),
                           df["Contact 1"].str.extract(r'^\d{8,10} (\d{8,10})$'),
                           df["Contact 2"])
```

Also we need to update the first column:

```py
df["Contact 1"] = df["Contact 1"].str.replace(r'^(\d{8,10}) \d{8,10}$', r'\1')
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: @Chris Now is using `np.where` to only assign a value to `Contact 2` in the event that it is not already empty.

Comment: Still need to fix the first column!

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it and it works for every row except for the row that has a "Contact 2" value, where it gets overwritten to nan. I don't know why is that happening since the logic seems fine.

I'm sorry I forgot to mention that instead of blanks, my real dataframe has None values. So I changed it to None as shown below 
`df["Contact 2"] =np.where(df["Contact 2"] == None, df["Contact 1"].str.extract(r'^\d{8,10} (\d{8,10})$'),df["Contact 2"])`
 but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user16170404 Use `isnull()` on the column to check for `None`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you :) `isnull()` worked for my small dataframe, except I'm still losing my 'Contact 2' value. Anyway, I ran the code on my real dataframe of 75,000 rows but it gets killed with error "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)"  and I believe it's due to excessive memory usage.